# How to get similarity score for observations in a Dataframe in R

Tags: r, dplyr, similarity, feature-extraction, data-cleaning

I have a dataset having survey responses collected from people multiple times. Following is an example dataset.

```
library(dplyr)
DATA <- data.frame(ID = c(1,22,22,333,333,333,4444,4444,4444,4444),
               Gender = c("M","F","F","M","M","NotAvailable","M","M","F","NotAvailable"),
               MaritalStatus = c("W","M","M","UM","NotAvailable","UM","M","UM","W","NotAvaiable"),
               Name = c("Available","NotAvailable","NotAvailable","Available","Available","Available","Available","NotAvailable",
                        "Available","NotAvailable"),
               Age = c(20,30,30,21,22,23,33,33,33,34),
               EmailIND = c(0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1),
               Irrelevant = c(12,3123,312,343,554,66,67,56,123,434)
    )
> DATA
     ID       Gender MaritalStatus         Name Age EmailIND Irrelevant
1     1            M             W    Available  20        0         12
2    22            F             M NotAvailable  30        1       3123
3    22            F             M NotAvailable  30        1        312
4   333            M            UM    Available  21        0        343
5   333            M  NotAvailable    Available  22        0        554
6   333 NotAvailable            UM    Available  23        1         66
7  4444            M             M    Available  33        1         67
8  4444            M            UM NotAvailable  33        1         56
9  4444            F             W    Available  33        1        123
10 4444 NotAvailable   NotAvaiable NotAvailable  34        1        434
```

My objective here is to create 2 variables :

1. Similarity Flag - Inidcating 1 if information provided by indivdiual was same in each survey else 0.
2. Magnitude Similarity - Giving a numerical score of how similar information was provided by individual across different survey.

Following is my solution:

```
getSimRespFlag <- function(x){
  return(as.numeric(length(unique(x)) == 1))
}
```

Irrelevant represents those columns which wont be used for this analysis

```
numberOfCols <- ncol(DATA)
similarity_DATA <- DATA%>%
                select(-c(Irrelevant))%>%
                group_by(ID)%>%
                summarise_all(funs(getSimRespFlag))%>%
                mutate( SimilarResp_Flag = as.numeric((rowSums(.[2:(numberOfCols-1)])/(numberOfCols-2)) == 1),
                        Magnitude_Similarity = rowSums(.[2:(numberOfCols-1)])/(numberOfCols-2))%>%
                select(ID,SimilarResp_Flag,Magnitude_Similarity)

> similarity_DATA
# A tibble: 4 × 3
     ID SimilarResp_Flag Magnitude_Similarity
  <dbl>            <dbl>                <dbl>
1     1                1                  1.0
2    22                1                  1.0
3   333                0                  0.2
4  4444                0                  0.2

DATA <- left_join(DATA,similarity_DATA,by ="ID")

> DATA
     ID       Gender MaritalStatus         Name Age EmailIND Irrelevant SimilarResp_Flag Magnitude_Similarity
1     1            M             W    Available  20        0         12                1                  1.0
2    22            F             M NotAvailable  30        1       3123                1                  1.0
3    22            F             M NotAvailable  30        1        312                1                  1.0
4   333            M            UM    Available  21        0        343                0                  0.2
5   333            M  NotAvailable    Available  22        0        554                0                  0.2
6   333 NotAvailable            UM    Available  23        1         66                0                  0.2
7  4444            M             M    Available  33        1         67                0                  0.2
8  4444            M            UM NotAvailable  33        1         56                0                  0.2
9  4444            F             W    Available  33        1        123                0                  0.2
10 4444 NotAvailable   NotAvaiable NotAvailable  34        1        434                0                  0.2
```

Is there any  better way to get Similarity Flag and Magnitude of similarity like cosine similarity in case of documents (which has numeric values but I have both categorical and numeric). My dataset is large and this operation takes time so any fast solution will also work.